# Custom view in xml layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

I've created my own view by creating a subclass of the SurfaceView class.

However I can't figure out how to add it from the xml layout file. My current main.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<View
    class="com.chainparticles.ChainView"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

What have I missed?

Edit

More info

My view looks like this

```
package com.chainparticles;
public class ChainView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    public ChainView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }
// Other stuff
}
```

And it works fine like this:

```
ChainView cview = new ChainView(this);
setContentView(cview);
```

But nothing happens when trying to use it from the xml.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

    <com.chainparticles.ChainView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit:

After seeing the rest of your code it's probably throwing because you can't call `getHolder` in the constructor while being inflated. Move that to `View#onFinishInflate`

So:

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
}
```

If that doesn't work try putting that in an init function that you call in your `Activity`s onCreate after `setContentView`.

It was probably working before because when inflating from xml the constructor:
`View(Context, AttributeSet)` is called instead of `View(Context)`.

Comment: With my first layoutI just recieved a black screen, with this the app crashes instead.

Comment: Maybe these extra suggestions will help.

Comment: I got it! The key was that the xml called the constructor with Context and AttributeSet (as you said), so adding that constructor solved it. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11):

What you missed in your example was the tag name, it supposed to be "view" (first non-capital) not "View". Although you can put your class name as the tag name most of the time, it's impossible to do that if your class is inner class, because "$" symbol, which is used in Java to reference inner classes is restricted in XML tags.
So, if you want to use inner class in your XML you should write like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

    <view
      class="com.chainparticles.Foo$InnerClassChainView"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

The thing is that both "*view*" and "*View*" tags exist in the schema. "*View*" tag (started with capital letter) will generate a View class, while "*view*" tag, when parsed, will examine the class attribute.

Comment: @SamusArin   +1 for love him haha

Comment: Remember to add ALL the constructors.  If you are overriding View, there are 3 constructors: View(Context context), 
View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  and  
View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)

Comment: Awesome answer.. +1 for View and view tags difference